# How is This Code Being Processed?

Tags: java, jvm, int

When I run the following code:

```
int n = 20;
int result  = (n % 2)-1;
int nextResult = result + 1;

for(int i =0; i < 5; i++)
{ 
  n += 1; nextResult += 1;
  System.out.println("\n" + result + "\n" + nextResult);
}
```

i get the following result:

```
20
0

20
1

20
2

20
3

20
4
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

1. Is the formula for `result` and `nextResult` resolving on every iteration, or do I simply get the initial result?
2. If the answer to the above query is the former, is that typical of jvm's int variable processing?
3. Are there situations in which the reverse is the case?

Comment: What's stopping you from answering these questions yourself? Debug your program and see for yourself.

Comment: `result` only gets set once, so its value will only ever be one thing. (I'm not sure how you got `20` to output, it should be `-1`)

Comment: @f1sh I did run it myself. Its a little hard to wrap my head around it

Comment: @4castle so even if `nextResult` gets incremented after `result` gets incremented, the change in `result` value has no effect on `nextResult` value?

Comment: oh dear..I really hope I get a clear response before this gets locked..

Comment: @Nkem Instead of just running the program, use your debugger to step through each line of code you you can see what that line is doing. No need to wrap your head around the whole program just one line at a time.  If a line is too complicated, break it up into multiple lines so you can see what it is doing in as much detail as you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know what's the source of the OP's confusion, from my past experience with software novices.

This is a program, not a system of mathematical equations. The key insight here is that the program executes **line by line**. The line

```
int nextResult = result + 1;
```

is an assignment; it takes the value of `result` **at that specific moment**, adds one to that, and assigns that value to `nextResult`. It does **not** establish a relationship between result and nextResult so that the latter will always be one larger than the former. Either variable may be assigned to at some point down the road without affecting the other.

This, for example, is a valid program:

```
a = 1
b = 2;
a = b;
```

If you treat this as a system of equations, it's nonsense. If you treat it as a series of processing instructions - calculate the right hand side, assign to the variable in the left hand side, move on to the next line - there's nothing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Variables are only resolved when they are set with an `=` of some kind. Changing a variable which has a relationship to another variable won't update the other variable; you have to do that explicitly.

```
int n = 20;
int result  = (n % 2)-1;
int nextResult = result + 1;

for(int i =0; i < 5; i++) { 
    n += 1;
    result = (n % 2)-1; //update result because n changed
    nextResult = result + 1; //update nextResult because result changed
    System.out.println("\n" + result + "\n" + nextResult);
}
```

Comment: ...So basically the after `result`  value is changed, and  `nextResult` value is incremented, the new value of `result` has no effect whatsoever on `nextResult`?